# How to override shipping address without checkbox in PayPal

Tags: laravel, paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal Api in my application, everything works just fine except for one thing; How can I override the shipping address in PayPal Payment without checking the **Make this my preferred shipping address** checkbox.

I want it to be automatically check or my shipping address MUST be automatically applied as my shipping address. Please see the code and screenshot below:

```
$patchReplace = new Patch();
$patchReplace->setOp('add')
            ->setPath('/transactions/0/item_list/shipping_address')
            ->setValue([
                "recipient_name" => "{$request->input('first_name')} {$request->input('last_name')}",
                "line1" => $request->input('address'),
                "line2" => $request->input('barangay'),
                "city" => $request->input('city'),
                "state" => $request->input('province'),
                "phone" => $request->input('contact_number'),
                "postal_code" => $request->input('zip'),
                "country_code" => $request->input('country')
            ]);

$patchRequest = (new PatchRequest())->setPatches([$patchReplace]);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, "Make this my preferred shipping address" is an option for the user to update their PayPal account to set the provided shipping address as the default for their account, it is not specific to a transaction, it won't change the shipping address for the current transaction. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve: are people making payments to you through PayPal?

Comment: Hi sam. What do you mean by "it is not specific to a transaction"? And yes, it is through paypal. But there is also an option for to choose via credit card.

Comment: That option means "update my PayPal account settings so that next time I place an order this address is used by default" -- it does not change anything to do with the _current_ transaction.

Comment: Sorry. can you explain it explicitly?